# Scrapy Request object is not always followed

Tags: python, object, request, scrapy, web-crawler

I am creating a crawler with scraper.  
My spider must go to start page which contains a list of links and link for next page.  
Then, it must follow each link, go to this link, get infos and return to main page.  
Finally, when spider followed each link of the page, it go to next page and begin again.

```
        class jiwire(CrawlSpider):
        name = "example"
        allowed_domains = ["example.ndd"]
            start_urls = ["page.example.ndd"]   

            rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("next-page\.htm", ),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="paging"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),)

        def parse_items(self, response):
                hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
                links = hxs.select('//td[@class="desc"]')
                for link in links :
                    link = title.select("h3/a/@href").extract()
                    request = Request("http://v4.jiwire.com/" + str(name), callback=self.parse_sub)
                    return(request)


        def parse_sub(self, response):
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            name = hxs.select('//div[@id="content"]/div[@class="header"]/h2/text()').extract()
            print name
```

I exmplain my code : I defined a rule to follow next pages.  
To follow each link of current page, I created a request object with the link getted and I return this object.  
normally, for each request return, I must see "print name" in parse_sub function.  
But only ONE  link has been follow (and no all), I don't understand why.  
It crawl fine the link, request object is created fine but it enter in parse_sub only once per page.  
  
Can you help me ?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I am back !  my problem come from my return statement.

The solution:

```
    for link in links :
        link = title.select("h3/a/@href").extract()
        request = Request(link, callback=self.parse_hotspot)
        yield request
```